# display the message box and sound simultaneously - VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, audio, vba

In the code below, the song is played first, after which the message is displayed. How to display the **Message Box** and **Sound Play** *simultaneously* in the code below?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal 
dwFlags As Long) As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\tada.wav", 0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
   Msgbox "Process completed successfully."
End Sub
```

Comment: The msgbox appears immediately and won't depend on you pressing OK to run the next line. Why not just swap the call playsound and msgbox lines around?

Comment: @spikey_richie `MsgBox` is modally displayed and halts execution until it returns (= the user dismisses it). The sound will only be played once the dialog is closed.

Comment: Can you show the assignments for `SND_ASYNC` and `SND_FILENAME` as well? (Although I assume the latter is set correctly, otherwise you'd get the wrong sound played.)